new to ubuntu and in general Linux as a whole
I'm trying to access my windows c drive and move my torrent file downloads etc and other goodies internally from my dual booted laptop. OK. I'm trying to access them through Linux. I've tried mounting the drive in "Disks" but it gives me error mounting /dev,nvme0n1p4 wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock etc
How do I access my files? And transfer them over to my Linux partition without USB etc? Is that possible?

Boot into Windows. Turn off fast boot from within Windows. Boot into Ubuntu. Try again with the Disks app.

Yes it's possible, however your windows file-system needs to be clean with everything written out to disk (fastboot has the file-system in an unclean state, with some fs details written to a hibernate/fastboot file as its faster to resume from).  If your fs or file-system is clean you should have no problems...
